# What's the best UPS unit for a home PC

Tags: battery, ups

I recently moved into a new house, and it seems that every time there's an electrical storm, the power will blink on and off quite frequently.  I was thinking of getting a [UPS (Uninterruptible power supply)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) for my home computer.   I don't need anything that will last for hours. Just something that can ride out the blips during electrical storms.  How do I find a unit that can supply enough power for my PC, while not going overboard and spending more money than I need to.

My current setup has a 450 Watt power supply.  I have a 19 inch non-widescreen monitor, a router, and a cable modem that I would like to attach to the unit.  My computer consists of an AMD 4200, 2 hard disks, 2 Gigs of RAM, a DVD Writer, and a TV Tuner. I also have speakers on my computer, but I think it's not so important if those cut out a little during a power outage.

Comment: Nice thing about most UPS is that they provide battery backup outlets *and* surge protection outlets, so be sure to only plug the mission critical things into the batter, and the others into surge protection only.

Comment: Maybe you should buy an UPS providing *true sine waves*, not PWM rectangular ones, electronics don't lime the latter too much.

Comment: If you can find a local seller, I'd recommend the *CYBERPOWER CP1500PFCLCD*, featuring true sine waves. Amazon has it. 900 W max at 6 outlets, so you can protect pretty much any PC equipment, probably except for your laser printer or your fully automatic coffee maker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

APC has a [calculator](http://www.apc.com/tools/ups_selector/index.cfm) to help you ballpark your requirements.

A few things to know before getting a UPS:

- They add a *little* redundancy to your system; not a lot
- The battery will need to be replaced every few years in order to get any meaningful use out of it.  I have an old battery than doesn't last 0.1 seconds on a full charge, it got me ~3 minutes of usage when it was new
- Some components can damage UPS's (laser printers for sure) so definately review the UPS manual

Comment: +1 for APC - I use them at my office, where I care for about 15 machines.  I find them reliable.  I also have used their calculator, and as you might guess, they will point you to something a little larger than you really need, but if you prefer peace-of-mind - go with their guidance.  Lastly, shop around, if you can time your purchase, the APC units are often on sale at Staples or Costco, etc. - keep an eye out for a sale.

Answer (score 1):

TrippLite makes nice UPS models for the home.  Follow the link below to something that is probably appropriate for your needs.

http://www.tripplite.com/en/products/product-series.cfm?txtSeriesID=669&EID=13721